# I want to implement Autocompletetextview in toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-tabs, autocompletetextview

Here is my code. I am using menu_search to display Search icon. Search_layout is showing autocompletetextview. I don't know where to initialize autocompletetextview in mainactivity.

**menu_search.xml**

```
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:name="search"
            android:title="search"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>

    </menu>
```

**search_layout.xml**

```
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_searchWidget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text">
            <requestFocus/>
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            setupViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            //setupTabIcons();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search,menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

Comment: publish your code snippet where you are trying to add AutocompleteTextview

Comment: Please my check my code

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
android:background="@color/color_white"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivShorting"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivLeftIcon"
        android:background="@drawable/search_drawable"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:hint="Search Job"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/color_outer_space"
        android:textColorHint="@color/color_outer_space"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add Toolbar to actionbar

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_menubar_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
```

follow bellow link to add ArrayList to AutocompleteTextView

http://androidexample.com/Show_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=105

Comment: Not working.. Getting following error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference"

Comment: Do u have created the adapter and also get data from array list  ?   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item);

Comment: No. I have my own Custom Adapter

Comment: I tried your adapter as well. Still it's showing same error `toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView_searchWidget);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can use MaterialSearchView

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/theme_primary" />

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView

http://joerichard.net/android/android-material-design-searchview-example/